# Passing FUllCalendar events to controller method

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I am trying to post the `fullCalendar` events to my controller action method, but for some reason json that I am passing from view to controller is coming as null. I tried all possible combination, like changing action argument to my model type, to string type even passing simple jason, all are coming as null in my action argument. Here is my Ajax code and controller method, I am sure it is a small issue but I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong.

```
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({

                header: {
                    left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                },

                defaultView: 'month',
                editable: true,
                alldayslot: false,
                selectable: true,
                slotminutes: 15,
                nextDayThreshold: "00:00:00",
                events: "/Home/FullCalendar",
                eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc)
                {

                    if (confirm("Even changed")) {
                        Update(event);

                    }

                    else revertFunc();

                },


            });


        function Update(event) {
            var datarow = new Object();
                 datarow.TaskId = event.id;
                datarow.StartDate = event.start;
                datarow.EndDate = event.end;

           debugger;
           $.ajax({

               type: "post",
               dataType: "json",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               data: JSON.stringify(datarow),
                url: "/Home/UpdateTask",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    debugger;
                }

            });

        }


  });
```

My Controller method

```
[HttpPost]
    public void UpdateTask(Tasks td)

    {

        //  Update event in database 




    }
```

Comment: Nice question, but highly depends on how you MVC works. If you use `Request.Form["TaskId"]` on `public void UpdateTask(Tasks td)`, is it null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres how i had this working originally (changed heavily now, great plugin is FullCalendar).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/BookingTwo/GetDiaryEvents/',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    editable: false,
    contentHeight: 700,
    selectable: false,        

    eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
        var mywhen = moment(event.start).format('MMM Do h:mm A') + ' - ' + moment(event.end).format('MMM Do h:mm A');
        $("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
        $("#endTime").html(moment(event.end).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
        $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
        $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
        $('#etad').html(event.etad);
        $('#etadsub').html(event.etadsub);
        $('#when').text(mywhen);           
        $('#fullCalModal').modal();
    },


    dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        var mywhen = moment(event.start).format('MMM Do h:mm A') + ' - ' + moment(event.end).format('MMM Do h:mm A');
        $("#customId").html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
        $("#LeaveStart").html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
        $("#LeaveFinish").html(moment(event.end).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
        $('#title').html(event.title);
        $('#StaffID').html(event.userId);
        $('#selectrole').html(event.RowId);
        $('#customdescription').html(event.description);
        $('#sicktype').html(event.ETADType);
        $('#sicksub').html(event.ETADSubType);
        $('#eventstatus').html(event.EventStatus);
        $('#when').text(mywhen);
        $('#popupEventForm').modal();
    }

});

$('#btnPopupCancel').click(function () {
    ClearPopupFormValues();
    $('#popupEventForm').hide();
});

$('#btnPopupSave').click(function () {

    $('#popupEventForm').hide();

    var dataRow = {
        'Id': $('#customId').val(),
        'Subject': $('#title').val(),
        'Description': $('#customdescription').val(),
        'StartTime': $('#LeaveStart').val(),
        'EndTime': $('#LeaveFinish').val(),           
        'SelectRole': $('#SelectRole').val(),
        //'Recurrence': $('#eventDuration').val(),
        //'AllDay': $('#eventDuration').val(),
        //'AllRoles': $('#eventDuration').val(),
        'ETADType': $('#SicknessType').val(),
        'ETADSubType': $('#SicknessSubType').val(),
        //'RecurrenceRule': $('#eventDuration').val(),
        //'EventDate': $('#eventDuration').val(),
        'StaffID': $('#StaffID').val(),
        //'EventStatus': $('#EventStatus').val()
        //'Duration': $('#eventDuration').val(),
        //'colourId': $('#eventDuration').val()


    }

    ClearPopupFormValues();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/BookingTwo/SaveEvent",
        data: dataRow,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == 'True') {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                alert('New event saved!');
            }
            else {
                alert('Error, could not save event!');
            }
        }
    });
});

function ShowEventPopup(date) {
    ClearPopupFormValues();
    $('#popupEventForm').show();
    $('#title').focus();
}

function ClearPopupFormValues() {
    $('#customId').val("");
    $('#title').val("");
    $('#LeaveStart').val("");
    $('#LeaveFinish').val("");
}


function UpdateEvent(EventID, EventStart, EventEnd) {

    var dataRow = {
        'id': EventID,
        'NewEventStart': EventStart,
        'NewEventEnd': EventEnd
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/BookingTwo/UpdateEvent",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataRow)
    });
}
```

});

And Here is the current Controller action

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveEvent(DiaryEvent events)
    {
        try
        {
            int submit = bookingService.Insert(events);
            //get record here to check if inserted
            if(submit > 0)
            {
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLog.Capture(ex);
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            //return some shit
        }
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
```